# "No data to display" showing up on AdMob in the App-Ads.txt section

Tags: error-handling, admob, app-store-connect, app-ads.txt

[image]

I'm not sure why my app doesn't show up. I have followed all the instructions for creating an app-ads.txt and it has been 3 days, but it is still not showing up. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried this link to find issues? https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9776740?hl=en

Comment: I did, but unfortunately I couldn’t find it there.